# How to preserve space argument when using $@?

Tags: bash

There are two bash scripts in the directory:

foo.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./bar.sh $@
```

bar.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $#
```

When I run `./foo.sh 1 " "`, get `1` instead of `2`. So `" "` argument is ignored when passed to `./bar.sh`.

How can I pass `" "` to `./bar.sh`?

Comment: The answer is almost always "use quotes". Read the answers (plural) to [When to wrap quotes around a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/258523) for some discussion and examples of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `"$@"` that preserves white space and even empty arguments.